# LyX forbids horizontal centering of tables inside a theorem environment!

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, theorems

How can I center a table in a, say, theorem environment in LyX ? When I have a centered table in the standart LR-mode writing mode everythings ok. But when I select the whole table and try to turn it into a theorem, by clicking on "`theorem`" in LyX's environment box, I get the message

```
The new layout does not permit the alignment previously used.
Setting to default.
```

And the table wanders to left inside the newly created theorem environment.

Looking at the source code LyX generates, when doing the things I just described, I can see that LyX forbids be to put the tabular environment inside a `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` environment as soon as the tabular environment is inside a `\begin{thm}` ... `\end{thm}` environment.

In plain LaTeX this works fine, therefor I can't see why LyX forbids this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LyX apparently doesn't allow centered paragraphs inside theorems (at least the two modules I tried). As a workaround, you can add the `center` environment in ERT's before and after the tabular.

[image]

Comment: I was actually hoping for a more elegant solution, but if there is none, then probably this is the best I can hope for.

Comment: @user10324 There may well exist a more elegant solution, as I'm hardly a LyX expert. This was just my first thought for a workaround.